# Initializer is overwriting second array

Tags: c++

I cannot solve this, I'm almost accepting the fact that it might be a memory issue with my machine at this point.

I have this initializer:

```
Search::Search(ifstream& inFile)
{

    int id = 0;
    int i = 0;

    inFile >> id;

    while (inFile) {

        if(i < SEARCH_DATA_SIZE) {

            SearchDataFirst[i] = id;
            SearchDataFirstSorted[i] = id;

        } else if(i >= SEARCH_DATA_SIZE) {

            SearchDataLast[i] = id;
            SearchDataLastSorted[i] = id;

        }

        i++;
        inFile >> id;
    }

}
```

And in my header i have private data like so:

> const int SEARCH_DATA_SIZE = 20;
>
> ```
> int SearchDataFirst[SEARCH_DATA_SIZE];
> int SearchDataLast[SEARCH_DATA_SIZE];
> int SearchDataFirstSorted[SEARCH_DATA_SIZE];
> int SearchDataLastSorted[SEARCH_DATA_SIZE];
> ```

The initializer is getting the first 20 ints from inFile, storing them, and then going to the next records and storing those in separate arrays,

When I do a print of the arrays, SearchDataFirstSorted has the values of SearchDataLast, even though there is no possible way ever that this could happen. SearchDataLastSorted has weird funky numbers.

SearchedDataFirst is fine.

I have never been this frustrated with a programming language.

Hopefully you can help.

There is nothing else going on, only the initializer is being called at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if `i >= SEARCH_DATA_SIZE`, then `SearchDataLast[i]` is pointing outside `SearchDataLast`! What you really need is something like this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < SEARCH_DATA_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        inFile >> id;
        SearchDataFirst[i] = id;
        SearchDataFirstSorted[i] = id;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < SEARCH_DATA_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        inFile >> id;
        SearchDataLast[i] = id;
        SearchDataLastSorted[i] = id;
    }
```

That is, you need to reset `i` back to zero after you're done populating `SearchDataFirst` and before you start populating `SearchDataLast`.

Comment: Got it, I see what you did there. Thank you for help! Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic doesn't make any sense. The best I can figure, you're trying to do something like this:

```
} else if(i >= SEARCH_DATA_SIZE) {
    SearchDataLast[i - SEARCH_DATA_SIZE] = id;
    SearchDataLastSorted[i - SEARCH_DATA_SIZE] = id;
}
```

in its current form every single element you try to write to in `SearchDataLast` and `SearchDataLastSorted` is beyond the array bounds (which does indeed lead to memory corruption).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
    else if(i >= SEARCH_DATA_SIZE) {

        SearchDataLast[i] = id;
        SearchDataLastSorted[i] = id;

    }
```

You're going past the bounds of `SearchDataLast` and `SearchDataLastSorted`, since they're of size `SEARCH_DATA_SIZE` and `i` is greater than or equal to that amount. What you probably want is `i - SEARCH_DATA_SIZE` as the indexes.

Because of this you're causing undefined behaviour, where in your case the compiler has allocated memory for each of the arrays in order. So you're basically skipping `SEARCH_DATA_SIZE` elements in `SearchDataLast`, and storing the values you want there in `SearchDataFirstSorted`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't ensure that you don't overrun the `SearchDataLast` and `SearchDataLastSorted` arrays.

When `i` gets beyond `SEARCH_DATA_SIZE`, you switch arrays, ...but... you continue indexing from `SEARCH_DATA_SIZE` which is bigger than the `SearchDataLast` array.

Presumably, you intended to write something like:

```
    else if (i >= SEARCH_DATA_SIZE)
    {
        SearchDataLast[i-SEARCH_DATA_SIZE] = id;
        SearchDataLastSorted[i-SEARCH_DATA_SIZE] = id;
    }
```

You would still need to ensure that you do not overflow the end of these arrays (by ensuring that `i` is not `2 * SEARCH_DATA_SIZE` or larger.